# Azure Container status waiting due to the ImagePullBackOff

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-aks

I'm new to the Azure AKS and docker. I followed the steps in [this](https://husseinsalman.com/deploying-a-multi-container-application-into-azure-kubernetes-part-2-containerize-the-application/) article.

Finally, I compleated all the steps and got this status.

[image]

But the external IP is not giving the actual output. I checked in the Azure portal, The container status is waiting. Am I missing anything here?[image]

Comment: it may take sometime how long did you wait?

Comment: did you actually push the container to the ACR?

Comment: I did these two things
docker push mywebregistry.azurecr.io/backend:v1
docker push mywebregistry.azurecr.io/frontend:v1
Any thing else I missed?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Yes, I wait one hr.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. Your docker image is in a private registry (ACR for instance) and you'll need to give it the registry credentials. 2. Your image is broken in some way. Can you check the pod logs? `kubectl get pods`, then `kubectl logs <pod-name>`.

Comment: @mmking

C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
backend-deployment-74794c5d94-nwb8r    0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          13h
customer-deployment-57d469cb94-n2mmj   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          14h
frontend-deployment-6bf8c8bcdd-xtcll   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          13h

C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl logs frontend-deployment-6bf8c8bcdd-xtcll
Error from server (BadRequest): container "frontend" in pod "frontend-deployment-6bf8c8bcdd-xtcll" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image

Comment: Three messages you need to add to the question. The first is that you need to provide the output of the command `kubectl describe svc frontent-service`. The second is the events of the failed pods. The third is that the screenshot of ACR which displays the images you pushed.

Comment: Please check if your image is in the remote repository. There is an official documentation about the process that you are trying to achieve: [Pushing image to repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-acr) and [Run Application on Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application). Let me know if this links helped you.

Comment: Pretty sure it's an auth issue (ACR being a private registry). Did you try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration)?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication will be needed to pull the images from ACR. We have to create a docker-registry secret for authentication. To do this, open Cloud Shell on the Azure Portal and run the command below.

```
> kubectl create secret docker-registry mysecretname  --docker-server=myacrname.azurecr.io --docker-username=myacrname--docker-password=myacrpwd --docker-email=myportalemail
```

Don’t forget to change your password and email address.
To access your password go to your Azure Container Registry go to
https://portal.azure.com/ » Your Container registry » Access keys

Finally make sure that docker image url in the you kubernetes yaml file is right

https://github.com/husseinsa/kubernetes-multi-container-app/blob/master/k8/frontend.yaml
https://github.com/husseinsa/kubernetes-multi-container-app/blob/master/k8/backend.yaml

> ```
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - name: backend
>     image: mywebregistry.azurecr.io/backend:v1
>     ports:
>     - containerPort: 80
> ```

put your image url in asure container registry